# Text field throwing error

Tags: java, swing

I have a program that has text fields that are filled out by the user. Based on what is selected in the comboBox, different fields are requires. I have an error handler for if a required field is left blank. For some reason, i keep getting an error for lastName, birthday, and depatermentName. Can anyone shed some light on why these errors are popping up even when these fields have data?

Here is my code...

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.util.StringJoiner;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class AddEmployeeDisplay extends JFrame
{
    private EmployeeQueries employeeQueries;

    private JPanel displayPanel;
    private JButton addEmpButton;
    private JButton clearButton;
    private JLabel firstNameLabel;
    private JTextField firstNameText;
    private JLabel lastNameLabel;
    private JTextField lastNameText;
    private JLabel SSNLabel;
    private JTextField SSNText;
    private JLabel birthdayLabel;
    private JTextField birthdayText;
    private JLabel employeeTypeLabel;
    private JComboBox<String> employeeTypeCombo;
    private JLabel departmentNameLabel;
    private JTextField departmentNameText;
    private JLabel grossSalesLabel;
    private JTextField grossSalesText;
    private JLabel commissionRateLabel;
    private JTextField commissionRateText;
    private JLabel baseSalaryLabel;
    private JTextField baseSalaryText;
    private JLabel bonusLabel;
    private JTextField bonusText;
    private JLabel hoursLabel;
    private JTextField hoursText;
    private JLabel wageLabel;
    private JTextField wageText;
    private JLabel weeklySalaryLabel;
    private JTextField weeklySalaryText;


    private static final String[] employeeType = {"", "BasePlusCommissionEmployee", "CommissionEmployee", 
                                        "HourlyEmployee", "SalariedEmployee"};

    // Constructor
    public AddEmployeeDisplay()
    {
        super("Add a New Employee");

        // Establish database connection
        employeeQueries = new EmployeeQueries();

        // Create the GUI
        displayPanel = new JPanel();
        employeeTypeLabel = new JLabel();
        employeeTypeCombo = new JComboBox<String>(employeeType);
        employeeTypeCombo.setMaximumRowCount(5);
        firstNameLabel = new JLabel();
        firstNameText = new JTextField();
        lastNameLabel = new JLabel();
        lastNameText = new JTextField();
        SSNLabel = new JLabel();
        SSNText = new JTextField();
        birthdayLabel = new JLabel();
        birthdayText = new JTextField();
        departmentNameLabel = new JLabel();
        departmentNameText = new JTextField();
        grossSalesLabel = new JLabel();
        grossSalesText = new JTextField();
        commissionRateLabel = new JLabel();
        commissionRateText = new JTextField();
        baseSalaryLabel = new JLabel();
        baseSalaryText = new JTextField();
        bonusLabel = new JLabel();
        bonusText = new JTextField();
        hoursLabel = new JLabel();
        hoursText = new JTextField();
        wageLabel = new JLabel();
        wageText = new JTextField();
        weeklySalaryLabel = new JLabel();
        weeklySalaryText = new JTextField();
        clearButton = new JButton();
        addEmpButton = new JButton();

        setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 10, 10));
        setSize(500, 600);
        setResizable(false);

        displayPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(16, 5, 4, 4));    

        employeeTypeLabel.setText("Employee Type: ");
        displayPanel.add(employeeTypeLabel);
        displayPanel.add(employeeTypeCombo);
        employeeTypeCombo.addItemListener(
            new ItemListener()
            {
                public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event)
                {
                    if(event.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED)
                    {
                        if(employeeTypeCombo.getSelectedItem().toString() == "BasePlusCommissionEmployee")
                        {
                            firstNameText.setEditable(true);
                            lastNameText.setEditable(true);
                            SSNText.setEditable(true);
                            birthdayText.setEditable(true);
                            departmentNameText.setEditable(true);
                            grossSalesText.setEditable(true);
                            commissionRateText.setEditable(true);
                            baseSalaryText.setEditable(true);
                            bonusText.setEditable(true);
                            hoursText.setEditable(false);
                            wageText.setEditable(false);
                            weeklySalaryText.setEditable(false);                            
                        }

                        if(employeeTypeCombo.getSelectedItem().toString() == "CommissionEmployee")
                        {
                            firstNameText.setEditable(true);
                            lastNameText.setEditable(true);
                            SSNText.setEditable(true);
                            birthdayText.setEditable(true);
                            departmentNameText.setEditable(true);
                            grossSalesText.setEditable(true);
                            commissionRateText.setEditable(true);
                            baseSalaryText.setEditable(false);
                            bonusText.setEditable(true);
                            hoursText.setEditable(false);
                            wageText.setEditable(false);
                            weeklySalaryText.setEditable(false);                            
                        }

                        if(employeeTypeCombo.getSelectedItem().toString() == "HourlyEmployee")
                        {
                            firstNameText.setEditable(true);
                            lastNameText.setEditable(true);
                            SSNText.setEditable(true);
                            birthdayText.setEditable(true);
                            departmentNameText.setEditable(true);
                            grossSalesText.setEditable(false);
                            commissionRateText.setEditable(false);
                            baseSalaryText.setEditable(false);
                            bonusText.setEditable(true);
                            hoursText.setEditable(true);
                            wageText.setEditable(true);
                            weeklySalaryText.setEditable(false);                            
                        }

                        if(employeeTypeCombo.getSelectedItem().toString() == "SalariedEmployee")
                        {
                            firstNameText.setEditable(true);
                            lastNameText.setEditable(true);
                            SSNText.setEditable(true);
                            birthdayText.setEditable(true);
                            departmentNameText.setEditable(true);
                            grossSalesText.setEditable(false);
                            commissionRateText.setEditable(false);
                            baseSalaryText.setEditable(false);
                            bonusText.setEditable(true);
                            hoursText.setEditable(false);
                            wageText.setEditable(false);
                            weeklySalaryText.setEditable(true);                         
                        }
                    }                       
                }
            }
        );

        firstNameLabel.setText("First Name: ");
        displayPanel.add(firstNameLabel);
        displayPanel.add(firstNameText);
        firstNameText.setEditable(false);

        lastNameLabel.setText("Last Name: ");
        displayPanel.add(lastNameLabel);
        displayPanel.add(lastNameText);
        lastNameText.setEditable(false);

        SSNLabel.setText("SSN: ");
        displayPanel.add(SSNLabel);
        displayPanel.add(SSNText);
        SSNText.setEditable(false);

        birthdayLabel.setText("Birthday: ");
        displayPanel.add(birthdayLabel);
        displayPanel.add(birthdayText);
        birthdayText.setEditable(false);

        departmentNameLabel.setText("Department Name: ");
        displayPanel.add(departmentNameLabel);
        displayPanel.add(departmentNameText);
        departmentNameText.setEditable(false);

        grossSalesLabel.setText("Gross Sales: ");
        displayPanel.add(grossSalesLabel);
        displayPanel.add(grossSalesText);
        grossSalesText.setEditable(false);

        commissionRateLabel.setText("Commission Rate: ");
        displayPanel.add(commissionRateLabel);
        displayPanel.add(commissionRateText);
        commissionRateText.setEditable(false);

        baseSalaryLabel.setText("Base Salary: ");
        displayPanel.add(baseSalaryLabel);
        displayPanel.add(baseSalaryText);
        baseSalaryText.setEditable(false);

        bonusLabel.setText("Bonus Amount: ");
        displayPanel.add(bonusLabel);
        displayPanel.add(bonusText);
        bonusText.setEditable(false);

        hoursLabel.setText("Hours: ");
        displayPanel.add(hoursLabel);
        displayPanel.add(hoursText);
        hoursText.setEditable(false);

        wageLabel.setText("Wage: ");
        displayPanel.add(wageLabel);
        displayPanel.add(wageText);
        wageText.setEditable(false);

        weeklySalaryLabel.setText("Weekly Salary: ");
        displayPanel.add(weeklySalaryLabel);
        displayPanel.add(weeklySalaryText);
        weeklySalaryText.setEditable(false);
        add(displayPanel);

        clearButton.setText("CLEAR");
        clearButton.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
                {
                    clearButtonActionPerformed(evt);
                }                   
            }
        );

        add(clearButton);

        addEmpButton.setText("Add New Employee");
        addEmpButton.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
                {
                    addEmpButtonActionPerformed(evt);
                }
            }
        );

        add(addEmpButton);

        addWindowListener(
            new WindowAdapter()
            {
                public void windowClosing(WindowEvent evt)
                {
                    employeeQueries.close();
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
        );

        setVisible(true);       
    }

    private void clearButtonActionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        // Clear the fields so that a new entry may be made.
        SSNText.setText("");
        SSNText.setEditable(false);
        firstNameText.setText("");
        firstNameText.setEditable(false);
        lastNameText.setText("");
        lastNameText.setEditable(false);
        birthdayText.setText("");
        birthdayText.setEditable(false);
        employeeTypeCombo.setSelectedItem("");
        departmentNameText.setText("");
        departmentNameText.setEditable(false);
        grossSalesText.setText("");
        grossSalesText.setEditable(false);
        commissionRateText.setText("");
        commissionRateText.setEditable(false);
        baseSalaryText.setText("");
        baseSalaryText.setEditable(false);
        bonusText.setText("");
        bonusText.setEditable(false);
        hoursText.setText("");
        hoursText.setEditable(false);
        wageText.setText("");
        wageText.setEditable(false);
        weeklySalaryText.setText("");
        weeklySalaryText.setEditable(false);
    }

    // Handles call when addEmpButton is clicked
    private void addEmpButtonActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
    {
        int result = 0;
        StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(System.lineSeparator());
        if (employeeTypeCombo.getSelectedItem().toString() == "")
            joiner.add("Employee type missing.");
        if( SSNText.getText() == "" )
            joiner.add("SSN missing.");
        if( firstNameText.getText() == "" )
            joiner.add("First name missing.");
        if( lastNameText.getText() == "" );
            joiner.add("Last name missing.");
        if( birthdayText.getText() == "" );
            joiner.add("Birthday missing.");
        if( departmentNameText.getText() == "" );
            joiner.add("Department name missing.");

        if( joiner.length() != 0 )
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,
                    joiner.toString(),
                    "Error in input", 
                    JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
            return;
        }

        // Add base plus commission employee data to BasePlusCommissionEmployee table
        if (employeeTypeCombo.getSelectedItem().toString() == "BasePlusCommissionEmployee")
        {
            if( grossSalesText.getText() == "" )
                joiner.add("Gross sales missing.");
            if( commissionRateText.getText() == "" )
                joiner.add("Commission rate missing.");
            if( baseSalaryText.getText() == "" )
                joiner.add("Base salary missing.");
            if( bonusText.getText() == "" )
                joiner.add("Bonus missing.");

            if( joiner.length() != 0 )
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,
                        joiner.toString(),
                        "Error in input", 
                        JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                return;
            }

            result = 1;

            employeeQueries.addBPCEmp(SSNText.getText(), grossSalesText.getText(), commissionRateText.getText(),
                                                    baseSalaryText.getText(), bonusText.getText());
        }

        // Add commission employee data to CommissionEmployee table
        if (employeeTypeCombo.getSelectedItem().toString() == "CommissionEmployee")
        {
            if( grossSalesText.getText() == "" )
                joiner.add("Gross sales missing.");
            if( commissionRateText.getText() == "" )
                joiner.add("Commission rate missing.");
            if( bonusText.getText() == "" )
                joiner.add("Bonus missing.");

            if( joiner.length() != 0 )
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,
                        joiner.toString(),
                        "Error in input", 
                        JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                return;
            }

            result = 1;

            employeeQueries.addCEmployee(SSNText.getText(), grossSalesText.getText(),
                                                        commissionRateText.getText(), bonusText.getText());
        }

        // Add hourly employee data to HourlyEmployee table
        if (employeeTypeCombo.getSelectedItem().toString() == "HourlyEmployee")
        {
            if( hoursText.getText() == "" )
                joiner.add("Hours missing.");
            if( wageText.getText() == "" )
                joiner.add("Wage missing.");
            if( bonusText.getText() == "" )
                joiner.add("Bonus missing.");

            if( joiner.length() != 0 )
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,
                        joiner.toString(),
                        "Error in input", 
                        JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                return;
            }

            result = 1;

            employeeQueries.addHEmployee(SSNText.getText(), hoursText.getText(),
                                                        wageText.getText(), bonusText.getText());
        }

        // Add salaried employee data to SalariedEmployee table
        if (employeeTypeCombo.getSelectedItem().toString() == "SalariedEmployee")
        {
            if( weeklySalaryText.getText() == "" )
                joiner.add("Weekly salary missing.");
            if( bonusText.getText() == "" )
                joiner.add("Bonus missing.");

            if( joiner.length() != 0 )
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,
                        joiner.toString(),
                        "Error in input", 
                        JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                return;
            }

            result = 1;

            employeeQueries.addSEmployee(SSNText.getText(), weeklySalaryText.getText(), bonusText.getText());
        }

        // Add Employee data to Employee table
        result += 1;

        employeeQueries.addEmp(SSNText.getText(), firstNameText.getText(), lastNameText.getText(), birthdayText.getText(),
                                            employeeTypeCombo.getSelectedItem().toString(), departmentNameText.getText());

        if(result == 2)
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Employee added!", "Employee added", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

        else
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Employee not added!", "Error", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);     

        // Clear the fields so that a new entry may be made.
        clearButtonActionPerformed(evt);
    }





    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        AddEmployeeDisplay addEmployeeDisplay = new AddEmployeeDisplay();
    }

}
```

Comment: use .equals to compare string objects

Comment: `String` are always to be compared using `string1.euals ( string2 )`, not with `==`. Moreover,instead of attaching a `WindowListener`, simply add this line inside `AddEmployeeDisplay` class's constructor `setDefaultCloseOperation ( JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE )`. And do read about [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/). The way you starting `Swing` application is questionable, since `Swing` is to be started on `Event Disptacher Thread ( EDT )`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of saying `if(employeeTypeCombo.getSelectedItem().toString() == "CommissionEmployee")`, say `if(employeeTypeCombo.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("CommissionEmployee"))`.
Since `String` is a class, it uses methods to see if something is equal. It's not a primitive type (like `int` or `boolean`), but a class just like the one you are programming in.